# Why aren't my foreign key reference properties reflecting the foreign key ID property values?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1, ef-code-first

I have a `Candidate` entity, with some associations exampled below. I have a view model that doesn't have the reference properties, just the foreign key properties, and I am using AutoMapper to map the view model back to an entity. When I try and save the entity, I get validation errors telling me that e.g. *The Title field is required.* because although my `TitleId` has a valid value, `Title` is still null.

```
public class Candidate
{
...
    [Required]
    public string RefNum { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("TitleId")]
    [Required]
    public Title Title { get; set; }
    public Guid TitleId { get; set; }
...
}
```

PS, I can see how the `Required` attribute is causing trouble here, but how else do I insist that TitleId must be a valid ID, not just an empty Guid?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the `[Required]` attribute. It doesn't guarantee anyway that your Guid is not empty because an empty Guid `{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}` is a valid Guid which is a valid `uniqueidentifier` column value in the database. (`Guid` is a `struct` which cannot be `null`.) You are responsible to set the correct value of the Guid. Because the `Guid` is not nullable EF will detect the relationship as required anyway.

Alternatively you can also turn off the validation for the context instance...

```
context.Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = false;
```

...to avoid the error. You can also configure the mapping in Fluent API (`HasRequired/WithRequired`) instead of using the data annotation to avoid the validation error.

Comment: Ya, thanks. I sort of figured as much, but it's not quite spelled out that nicely elsewhere.