# Code First Fluent API validation not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-4.3

There is a class - it's a common class nothing special:

```
public class Trader{

public Guid UserId {get;set;}
public int TraderId { get; set; }
public string FirstName { get; set; }
public string LastName { get; set; }
public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
public string Skype { get; set; }
public string Photo { get; set; }
public string Email { get; set; }

public virtual User User { get; set; }
}
```

Mapping:

```
 public TraderMap()
        {
            this.ToTable("Trader", "General");
            this.HasKey(a => a.TraderId);
            this.HasRequired(a => a.User).WithMany().HasForeignKey(a => a.UserId);
            Property(a => a.UserId).HasColumnName("UserID").IsRequired();
            Property(a => a.TraderId).HasColumnName("TraderID").IsRequired();

            Property(a => a.FirstName).HasMaxLength(50).IsRequired();
            Property(a => a.LastName).HasMaxLength(50).IsRequired();
            Property(a => a.PhoneNumber).HasMaxLength(25).IsRequired();
            Property(a => a.Skype).HasMaxLength(50).IsOptional();
            Property(a => a.Photo).HasMaxLength(100).IsOptional();
            Property(a => a.Email).HasMaxLength(100).IsRequired();
        }
```

**When I leave FirstName or other fields that have IsRequired() empty in the form (View) the validation do not kick in.** It just runs into the error:

> Validation failed for one or more entities. See
>   'EntityValidationErrors' property for more details.

Unfortunately this error doesn't say too much. I was digging a little deeper but the only thing I was able to get was

> Invalid column name discriminator.

I thought it would be some forgotten inheritance somewhere (for User class) but I haven't found anything suspicious.

The problem is that when I use attributes in the Trader class everything works as supposed.

```
   public class Trader{

    public Guid UserId {get;set;}
    public int TraderId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public string Skype { get; set; }
    public string Photo { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    public virtual User User { get; set; }
    }
```

With attributes the validation works ok and @Html.ValidationMessageFor starts to display error messages and it doesn't allow to send NULL values.

Do you have any suggestion what would be the problem with my mapping?

**UPDATE 1**
In fact the attributes above are a possible solution to this problem.

Comment: Can you post your User class and mapping?

Comment: I don't understand.  Clearly validation *IS* working, when you try to insert blanks the error is "Validation failed", so validation is working fine.

Comment: "Validation errors thrown based on the Fluent API configurations will not automatically reach the UI, but you can capture it in code and then respond to it accordingly." from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/data/gg193959.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were both right, I was under false assumption.

**[Required] is not an equivalent of .IsRequired()**

There are several possible solutions:

1) **The quick & easy**: [Attributes](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc4/adding-validation-to-the-model)

> **Model Configuration overrides and Validation**
>
> With CodeFirst it is possible to override the configuration of the
>   model defined with validation attributes, e.g. in the OnModelCreating
>   method. Reconfiguring model affects validation since validation should
>   use the actual model configuration – blindly use of attributes would
>   cause validation errors for values that could be valid according to
>   the overrides made in OnModelCreating(). Here are the three special
>   cases for overrides made in OnModelCreating:
>
> - If a property was decorated with [Required] attribute and was reconfigured as optional (.IsOptional() method) the [Required]
>     attribute will be removed and as a result ignored when validation
>     happens
> - If a property was decorated with [StringLength] or [MaxLength] attribute and then was configured with new length
>     (.HasMaxLength() method) new maximum length will be used if possible
> - If a property was decorated with [StringLength] or [MaxLength] attribute and then was defined to be allowed maximum
>     length (.IsMaxLength) then the attribute will be removed (if possible)
>     and the length of the property value will not be checked
>
> Note that the above changes will be effective only if a property was
>   decorated with some validation attributes. So, setting property as
>   required (.IsRequired()) will not cause the property be validated
>   against null value.
>   See [EF Feature CTP5: Validation](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2010/12/15/ef-feature-ctp5-validation.aspx)

2) **A quick fix** but it's a dirty one as Mystere Man suggested
http://thedatafarm.com/blog/data-access/capturing-code-first-fluent-api-validationresults-to-display-in-mvc3-views/

http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2010/10/service-location-pt6-model-validation.html

3) **The heavy one**: [The Validation Application Block in Enterprise Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff664356%28v=pandp.50%29.aspx)
http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2009/10/enterprise-library-validation-example-for-aspnet-mvc-2.html but Enterprise Library is very often considered as an overkill

4) **Validation nirvana**: [FluentValidation](http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/) looks very promising and I'll definitely give it a try.
http://www.nuget.org/packages/FluentValidation.MVC3
Cons: Not the best approach in an n-layer app. It's primarily focused on Views.

5) **N-Layer**
http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/models-(data)/validating-with-a-service-layer-cs
This approach leads to problems with a validation on the client side so it must be solved separately.

Comment: That's not a solution.  That's a workaround.  It's very bad practice to use exceptions to deal with expected (and common) situations.  Exceptions are, as the name implies, Exceptional.  That is, they should only occur when something that is unplanned happens.  This is a very poor choice of dealing with the issue

Comment: Well, it answered my question pretty well and there is a link in the discussion to a Brad Wilson's blog http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2010/10/service-location-pt6-model-validation.html that is a good start.

Answer (score 4):

Validation only kicks in if you use 'data annotations' - while HasRequired does the mapping - data annotations attributes do both the mapping and the validation part.
i.e. for your views to validate I believe you'd have to place annotations/attributes on your properties.

That's often used to 'distinguish' in between just 'mapping' and both mapping and validating. i.e. if you want both use the attributes, if you want just mapping use the fluent configuration.

A related answer here also https://stackoverflow.com/a/9310435/417747 or https://stackoverflow.com/a/9789984/417747

EDIT: and this one is even closer to what you need, thanks to Justin
[How to make Fluent API configuration work with MVC client side validation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8894367/how-to-make-fluent-api-configuration-work-with-mvc-client-side-validation)

Answer (score 4):

I think you are confusing EF Model validation with MVC validation.  MVC knows nothing about EF or vice versa.  They are seperate technologies that work well together.

When you define validation on the fluent data model, you are only defining validation for Entity Framework.  This clearly works as when you try to save changes, EF fails and complains that Validation Failed.

Again, this has nothing to do with MVC validation, and the two do not work together for the most part (one exception is that if you are using a POCO class and use Data annotations, some of the annotations work in both MVC and EF, but some do not.  It's not good practice to use your data model directly in your view, so this is largely a moot point.)